# change selected item of selectonemenu primefaces by managedbean of javascript

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I want to change the selected value of this `selectOneMenu` either by managed bean or javascript:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="edit-article-famille" widgetVar="editFamille"
    required="true" requiredMessage="Veuillez choisir une famille"
    value="#{articlesMB.selectedFamille}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="selectionner famille" itemValue=""/>
  <f:selectItems value="#{articlesMB.listFamilles}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

How can I do it?
In the primefaces user guide, they don't talk about that.

Comment: Do you want to set value initially when page is loaded, later when something happens on page?

Comment: initially I don't have problem, the problem is when something happens on page

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set value of your `p:selectOneMenu` with `widgetVar` in JavaScript:

```
editFamille.selectValue(value);
```

`value` is value of `selectItem`.

Or in more recent versions of PrimeFaces via

```
PF('editFamille').selectValue(value)
```

Comment: hey its a old answer but coult you tell me where you found the functions for the menu which can be used with js ? can't find a documentary for this stuff

Comment: There is a section for each component in documentation called "Client Side API". You can find it there.