# Selecting option in p:selectOneMenu using JS

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm trying to pre-select the country of user in a selectOneMenu using javascript.
The problem is that when the page initially loads the list is still on the first element. However if I click on the arrow to expand the list, and then click somewhere else on the page to make the list disappear, then the value is the one set by javascript.

```
<p:selectOneMenu styleClass="inputField selectOneMenuColored" required="true" editable="false" id="country" value="#{subscribeUser.user.countryBean}" converter="#{countriesConverter}" effect="fold">
   <f:selectItems value="#{countriesConverter.countries}" var="country" itemLabel="#{country.shortName}" itemValue="#{country}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

and the javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<h:body id="whole" onload="setSelectedIndex('form:country_input',geoplugin_countryName());">
...
function setSelectedIndex(menuId, val){
    var menu = document.getElementById(menuId);
    var opts = menu.options;
    for( j = 0; j < opts.length; j++) {
        if(opts[j].value == val) {
            opts[j].selected= "true";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One question: Why do you try this in this complicated way?

Comment: One response: because I'm stupid and don't know the easy way.

Comment: Setting a value in the `#{subscribeUser.user.countryBean}` bean?

Comment: Or using the PrimeFaces javascript api

Comment: @HatemAlimam: And it was an honest question (ok maybe formulated less optimally from my mobile phone). There might have been a very valid reason todo it client side…  although doing it via the javascript api is client side to. Always wonder why people do not use documentation or even know that these 'complex' jsf components have a client-side api#{subscribeUser.user.countryBean}

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm not sure, maybe the fact that geoplugin_countryName() is passing some value, maybe from a map, since "geoplugin" has something to do with maps. Anyhow the client-side api is not documented well, actually to know these JS functions you should read the source code. I'm working on a cool tool to document this API, and I'm going to make it public once it's ready, but it's taking so much time to dig into the source code and to document it in a nice jsfiddle like website.

Comment: And now with a little more time…  there even is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741738/change-selected-item-of-selectonemenu-primefaces-by-managedbean-of-javascript

Comment: Here's a screenshot for this tool. If you are interested you can help on github :) http://i.imgur.com/0A6US87.png?1

Comment: This is escalating again… ;-) What sourcecode? Page 433 in the 5.2 docs. And I'll definately have a look at the tool. PF showcase often references wrong pages in the docs.

Comment: @Kukeltje I do use the primefaces doc a lot! I tried doing it through the bean before but I had some problems with the ip getting the ipv6 instead of ipv4. There are multiple post on SO that explain the same problem, but failing a bit to resolve that I went with what I thought to be the "easy" way out. It was stupid though because I need the ip for my failed attemps to sign in and remember me feature. Kinda went from one problem to two there.  Anyway my first comment was meant to be friendly maybe it came the wrong way.

Comment: No, I did not directly see it as really unfriendly (ok a little ;-)). Lets both blame @HatemAlimam who still did not tell where the tool is in github.

Comment: @Kukeltje ahaha, well I'm on vacation now far far away from my laptop :D it's private repo on github, I'll make sure you would get an invitation once I come back, you can find my email in my profile :) have nice weekend.

Comment: @Ced don't worry man, non is taken here on SO, a little sense of humor wouldn't kill tho :)

Comment: @HatemAlimam How condescending.. From all the combinations of words you could have used to tell me you were joking you tell me I've no sens of humor.

Comment: @Ced absolutely not, I was referring to myself that if I made a joke in a situation where you are asking a serious question that wouldn't do harm :) I didn't intend to offense anybody.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the goal but the answer is this:

Select by value:

```
PF('selectOneMenuWV').selectValue('3')
```

Select by label:

```
PF('selectOneMenuWV').selectItem(PF('selectOneMenuWV').jq.find('.ui-selectonemenu-item[data-label*="Option Label"]'))
```

Note that you should define a widgetVar, which is selectOneMenuWV in this example.

```
<p:selectOneMenu ... widgetVar="selectOneMenuWV">
```

Comment: Using JQuery should work as well: PF('selectOneMenuWV').selectItem($('[data-label="Option Label"]'))

Comment: @PedroPinheiro: Yes, but I think this selector is way more expensive (going through the whole document and not relative to the component)