# How do I set the selected item from p:selectOneListBox using javascript/jquery

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to  dynamically set the selected item in the selectOneListbox using a button.

xhtml

```
<p:selectOneListbox  id="basic1" widgetVar='commmentWidget'  styleClass="commentClass" value="#{decisionTreeBean.option1}" style=" font-size: 12px;background-color:white;width:17em; height:13em; border-style:solid !important;border-width:0.5px !important; border-color:grey !important;" >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{decisionTreeBean.commentType}" var="X"
                            itemLabel="#{X}" itemValue="#{X}" />
                    </p:selectOneListbox>
```

Jquery

```
jQuery(".generateBtn").on("click",function(event){
                    name=PF('commmentWidget').selectItem($('.ui-selectonelistbox-item[data-label*="Other"]'));
                    console.log(name);

                });
```

This is not working. Also, I do not have val() method on my widgetVar.

Comment: Sure your `$('.ui-selectonelistbox-item[data-label*="Other"]')` selector is returning the right node?And doing it like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866658/selecting-option-in-pselectonemenu-using-js is less expensive selecting the node

Comment: I don't see any `data-label` attributes on the selectonelistbox items, not even a `.ui-selectonelistbox-item`...

Comment: Following the solution provided in the link you shared.  When I try to use PF('selectOneMenuWV').selectValue('3') --> It gives me selectValue is not a function error. In the browser console also I can see that this method is not present in the prototype of PF('selectOneMenuWV').

I modified my elements to try and select by label and it doesn't work either
<p:selectOneListbox widgetVar='commmentWidget'>
<f:selectItems styleClass=".ui-selectOneListbox-item" value="#{decisionTreeBean.commentType}" var="X" itemLabel="#{X}" itemValue="#{X}" data-label="#{X}"/>
</p:selectOneListbox>

Comment: Selection on value is indeed not possible for this component. I meant the label (second one) and that does not work without the right selector. Where did you read `<f:selectItems styleClass=".ui-selectOneListbox-item" value="#{decisionTreeBean.commentType}" var="X" itemLabel="#{X}" itemValue="#{X}" data-label="#{X}"/>` works? What does the **generated** html look like... Base your selector on that. I think you need to a jquery selector based on the  index and pass that resulting item to the selectItem...

Comment: PF('commmentWidget').selectItem(PF('commmentWidget').jq.find("ul.ui-selectlistbox-list li:eq(4)"));

this worked. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The PrimeFaces `p:selectOneListbox` does not have any attributes set on options/items so they can be used in 'jquery' selectors. So the 'index' in the list most be used for this component

```
PF('commmentWidget').selectItem(PF('commmentWidget').jq.find("ul.ui-selectlistbox-list li:eq(4)"));
```

Here, I used `li:eq(4)` to select the 4th element from the list.